# how to install mysql on mac?

Tags: mysql-5.5, installation, mac-os-x, client

My Mac runs Mac OS X, version 10.7.5., so it's a 64 bit system.

First, I downloaded `mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg`.

Then I double clicked `mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg`, it's mounted, and shows

1. `mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.pkg` -> I double-clicked it to run, after clicked buttons a few times it's said to be successfully installed. However, I could not see anything in `Applications`.
2. `MySqlStartupItem.pkg` -> I double-clicked to run, also successfully done. However, I still could not see anything in `Applications`.
3. `MySQL.prefPane` -> I double-clicked it to run. Now I see a window jumped out, with a button <kbd>Start/Stop MySQL Server</kbd>, I clicked it, now it says "The MySQL Server Instance is *running*".

I'm a bit lost here:

Q1. Why until now there's nothing in the `Applications`? I can't see any item or folder like mysql there. Is it that every time I want to run mysql, I have to mount the installation package?

Q2. What did `MySQLStartupItem.pkg` install?

Q3. Are there any client side tools inside the installation package? I mean, for example, Microsoft SQL Server for Windows, there are Microsoft SQL Server; and there are Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, which serves as a client tool to browse databases and doing queries; also, if I download "Microsoft SQL Server Express with Tools" package, it will install both. Does `mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg` contain only the server, or also a client tool inside?

Comment: "*Are there any client side tools inside the installation package*". Yes: the `mysql` commandline tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL installs the database engine.  Which you run and start from the terminal/bash/shell.

You will need to download the MySQL workbench for a GUI.

[phpmMyAdmin](http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion/) is another choice which runs in the browser.

Sounds like you have MySQL installed.  You just need to setup a GUI now.

Q1. why until now there's nothing in the applications? I can't see any item or folder like mysql there. is it that every time i want to run mysql, i have to mount the installation package?

A1: The dB engine is installed you have to start and stop it using terminal window.

```
shell> sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
shell> sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
```

Q2. what does MySQLStartupItem.pkg installed?

A2: The Startup Item installation adds a variable MYSQLCOM=-YES- to the system configuration file /etc/hostconfig.

Q3. Is there any client side tools inside the installation package? I mean, for example, Microsoft SQL Server for Windows, there are Microsoft SQL Server; and there are Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, which serves as a client tool to browse databases and doing queries; also, if i download "Microsoft SQL Server Express with Tools" package, it will install both. does "mysql-5.5.28-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg" contains only the server, or also a client tool inside?

A3:  Lots.  phpMyAdmin for browser.  And MySQLWorkBench equal to SQL Server Management Studio (Browse dB's and other objects)

Comment: thanks Craig, it works! :) let me try get familiar to MySQLWorkBench :)

Comment: Shouldn't the mysql commandline ("client side tool") be part of a base installation?

Answer (score 4):

You can install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install mysql
```

This will install the mysql deamon and the cli tool.

Answer (score 1):

This package actually also installs the command-line interface (CLI) for MySQL, but does not put it in your $PATH.
The solution is to first run the two commands below in a terminal:

```
$ echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin" >> ~/.profile
$ source ~/.profile
```

Then you can use the CLI as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html).